# Not able to open LUIS application on new portal

Tags: azure-language-understanding

MS has changed their LUIS portal. Now I am facing issue in opening the lUIS application. It stuck right on the page where all my LUIS applications are visible. Screenshot is shown below where it hangs. Is there some issue with new portal? Please help if someone has the solution to this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I knew it later that issue was occurring only in office intranet. There was no issue at home internet. I got it resolved by updating some privacy certificates.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that refreshing the page, or opening in a private browser window doesn't resolve the issue you're seeing?

If not, contact us at lusupport@microsoft.com and we'll try to help you diagnose further.

Comment: The issue is resolved now. Thanks for your response.